# Mounting a Network Drive from a server with an Older version of SMB

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, cifs

I am currently running the following command to mount a server to my ubuntu machine.

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=tyler //[SERVER.IP]/ /media/Data`

But I get the following back

> mount error(115): Operation now in progress
>   Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

After speaking with our system admin, he says it has something to do with the server having an older version of SMB. This server is running "pam_smb-1.1.7-5", and the server is past what our admin says its end of life. I want to know how to tweak my command so that I can mount this server's drive to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several dialects or versions SMB understands, so you might try the following:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=tyler,vers=1.0 //[SERVER.IP] /media/Data
```

I neither have a trailing slash on source nor target... vers=1.0 should be used for old servers